# Using Settings with Complex Types

Tags: c#, configuration, settings

I am using the Settings class in my .NET project.  I notice in the editor that only certain types are available to be used as types for the individual properties in the Settings class.  What if I wanted to have a property that was an enumeration from my code or a generic collection for instance? How would I implement that?

I'm guessing that I can do it in a separate file using the partial class mechanism (since Settings is already defined as a partial class) but I want to see if anyone agrees with that and if there may be a way to do it within the editor.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question correctly, mostly the part about the editor and the "certain types are available to be used as types", can you clarify it or rephrase it?

Comment: Well if you create a Settings.settings file in your project there is an editor that you can use to set the datatype, name, etc. of a setting.  You pick the datatype for a setting from a TreeList box.  That TreeList box only references certain types.  Types in my assembly are not references.

Comment: referenced* not references ... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new "Settings" file to add a complex/user-defined type of choice.
Here is a how-to for a Enum.

**Step 1**. Create a Settings file

[image]

**Step 2**. Browse for type

[image]

**Step 3**. Select type (Namespace.TypeName)

[image]

**Step 4**. Ta da - Done

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you could simply specify the type and it would work.  Do you know if its possible to specify generic lists for settings in the same way?

Comment: Settings file basically let you return any type you want, as far as I know. But by Generic lists, you mean generic collections?

Comment: If you are trying to return different type of generic list depending on configuration data, wouldn't it be better to simply specify the "type" name instead of returning actual collection object?

Comment: I successfully added a user-defined setting type but then had trouble specifying the default values I wanted, since it was a complex type.  My type consists of three PointF's, so I eventually solved that by entering "f1.X=0,f1.Y=500, f2.X=500, f2.Y=500, f3.X=500, f3.Y=500".  Any complex type can be given a value in this fashion.

Answer (score 4):

To get a custom class to show in that list, make sure it has a default constructor as one of it's constructing options.  I learned this the hard way

Answer (score 2):

To answer Jeffrey's comment/question about whether Generic lists are possible in a settings file, the answer is yes. You just have to edit the Settings xml file manually. For example, if I have the following class:

```
public class UrlAlias
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I can create a List of these by right clicking on my settings file and select Open With...

Then choose XML / Text Editor, and set the "Type" value to the fully qualified class name, i.e:

```
Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyProject.SomeNamespace.UrlAlias]"
```

The full settings xml would look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="MyProject.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
 <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="UrlAliases" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CommonAddin.Data.DataSource.UrlAlias]" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)"></Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Once you do this, you should have a properly configured list of the custom settings object you created.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in a separate file as a part of a partial class is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to populate complex objects through configuration files, I would suggest using some Dependency Injection Framework s.a. Spring.Net.