# using generic list with custom class in the project settings becomes null after each run

Tags: c#, application-settings

i have a program which a part of it includes registering a user and then login in with that username pass he provided when he registered every time we run the program.
i know that this can be accomplished with a simple database but i want to use the project settings instead.
i have a user class:

```
class User
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public User(string name, string username, string password, string email)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

and then with the use of this post(from ismail-degani) in this page :
[Using Settings with Complex Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603501/using-settings-with-complex-types)
now i have created a list and this is the xml portion:

```
<Setting Name="Users" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Forum.User]" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```

now i can access this list and in the first i new it with this(i have a count which indicates is this the first run or not)

```
 private void Login_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (Settings.Default.Count == 0)
        {
            Settings.Default.Users = new List<User>();
        }
    }
```

and after adding some user to it i count++ and save it with settings.default.save() function.
but after running the program again my list becomes null again but the count is working just fine.
what the problem may be?

Update:
this is how i add a user and save the settings:

```
 private void sabtuser()
    {
        User newuser = new User(tb_name.Text, tb_username.Text, tb_password.Text, tb_email.Text);
        Settings.Default.Users.Add(newuser);
        Settings.Default.Count++;
        Settings.Default.Save();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**

Comment: please show the code of calling a list.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but perhaps you would need to have a (parameter-less) default constructor for the `User` class.

Comment: Slaks:it is not the matter of security or anything.it is just a simple program.elgonzo: i tried that and it didn't work either

Comment: @user3003613, i just have tested your case based on the code given in your question. A parameter-less default constructor is apparently not enough, the class also needs to be public. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save and reload your list of `User` objects to and from the settings file, you will need to make the class **public** and provide a **default (parameter-less) constructor**. (The default constructor can be private.)

```
public class User
{
    private User() {}

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public User(string name, string username, string password, string email)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Without the class being public, the data will not be written to the settings file.

Without the default parameter-less constructor, the data will not be read from the file again.

Comment: thanks it works after re running the program.but when i close the visual studio and start it again all the data is gone.

Comment: @user3003613, note that you write the settings in "user" scope, hence those settings are saved in the user's profile directory. Are you sure that your ran the application under the same user account?

Comment: yes.but now it works.all i have to do was to change the settings properties from never copy to copy if newer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to change the scope of the setting to Application level instead of User level.

```
<Setting Name="Users" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Forum.User]" Scope="Application">
  <Value Profile="(Default)" />
</Setting>
```